# Unable to start actvity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-camera

i am trying to develop android app to get number of cameras .. but every time i start the app it says: Unable to start actvity ComponentInfo.
So what i have to do to solve this problem .. i dont know where to start!
this is my code:

manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java file:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView v = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        //int x = checkcam();
        v.setText(Camera.getNumberOfCameras());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public int checkcam()
    {
        int no =Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if(no == 1)
        {
    return 1 ;
        }
        return 2;
    }
    }
```

logcat:

```
12-20 08:17:32.842: W/ResourceType(1280): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
12-20 08:17:32.842: D/AndroidRuntime(1280): Shutting down VM
12-20 08:17:32.852: W/dalvikvm(1280): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a9eba8)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): Process: com.example.test, PID: 1280
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-20 08:17:32.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     ... 11 more
12-20 08:20:15.382: I/Process(1280): Sending signal. PID: 1280 SIG: 9
12-20 08:21:33.692: W/ResourceType(1319): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
12-20 08:21:33.692: D/AndroidRuntime(1319): Shutting down VM
12-20 08:21:33.702: W/dalvikvm(1319): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a9eba8)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319): Process: com.example.test, PID: 1319
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-20 08:21:33.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: where is Logcat log?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: You're calling `v.setText()` with an `int` argument. Convert it to a `String`.

Comment: @Salah  use v.setText(Integer.toString((Camera.getNumberOfCameras()));

Comment: i get an error on v.setText((Camera.getNumberOfCameras().toString());

Comment: @MikeM. using autoboxing?  check new one

Comment: @MikeM. humm..I'm a student though:-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
int x = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        v.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```